# How to integrate Mustache with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, mustache

I'd like to replace default template of symfony1.4 with Mustache. To my surprise, I cannot find related approach by Google search.

Then, I suppose I can do it in simple way.

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
include('/path/to/Mustache.php');
   $m = new Mustache();
   echo $m->render('Hello {{planet}}', array('planet' => 'World!'));

   return sfView::NONE;
}
```

This looks clumsy. The main problems are:

Where to store the mustache template('Hello {{planet}}' in my case)?

Is it possible to replace default View Handler? so that I can put mustache template in templates folder and be transparent to action?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to implement it, is to create a new `sfView` implementation. Currently the `sfPhpView` is the default class for rendering the output. You could extend this class, and use Mustache for the rendering.

You could take a look [sfSmartyPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfSmartyPlugin) to see how they have implemented the Smarty Template Engine...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can take a look to twig. It's similar to musatche, and have a fair integration with symfony (twig is made by Fabien Potencier, the creator of symfony).
This is the plugin for symfony 1.x : https://github.com/henrikbjorn/sfTwigPlugin

Comment: hm~, I prefer mustache since it has mature JavaScript and PHP lib. Templates can be used in both browser side and server side.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am maybe too fabpot oriented.